# Docker on Debian Stretch gnutls_handshake() failed

Tags: docker, debian

I'm trying to install docker on my Stretch Debian.

I Followed [the guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-repository) but when I use "sudo apt-get update" I get :

> https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
>   gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has
>   failed.

"curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -"
returned OK

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libgnutls30` ?

Comment: Check your source list (/etc/apt/sources.list). Do you have others version than Stretch ?

Comment: @GAD3R apt-cache-policy returns : Installé : 3.5.8-5+deb9u2
  Candidat : 3.5.8-5+deb9u2
 Table de version :
 *** 3.5.8-5+deb9u2 500
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.5.8-5+deb9u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main amd64 Packages

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue on Debian Stretch installations that have been upgraded from Debian Jessie. The issue is described here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=834724. As described in the Debian bug report, you can fix this by removing the now obsolete library `libgnutls-deb0-28`.

If you have been a user of deb-multimedia like I have, removing this particular version of libgnutls is not entirely straight-forward because you probably have a version of `librtmp1` from deb-multimedia installed that is newer than what is provided by Debian Stretch and that depends on `libgnutls-deb0-28`. The solution is to first downgrade librtmp1 to the version provided by Stretch and then remove libgnutls:

1. `sudo apt install librtmp1=2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-1`
2. `sudo apt remove libgnutls-deb0-28`

If you are using aptitude instead of apt then aptitude will automatically suggest to downgrade `librtmp1`.

Comment: I ran into this bug via. the same circumstances, and your solution fixed it for me.  I had to do two other things before `libgnutls-deb0-28` could be removed: (1) upgrade `virtualbox` to the version available in `stretch-backports`, and (2) "downgrade" `ffmpeg`, which had also been installed from deb-multimedia.  "Downgrade" in quotes because it doesn't look like an actual downgrade, but just some version-number weirdness.